# Implement chart or ProgressBar in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to implement a ProgressBar or Chart in Android like this : [image: a bar with three sections marked with percentages]

So is there any 3rd party lib or any example I can follow? And actually what this view? Is it a progress bar with 3 stages or a chart?

Comment: Looks like a chart.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it with raw Android code or how to do it with MPAndroidChart?  I can explain how to do it with code. And you don't need a ProgressBar.

Comment: @krislarson how to do it with code ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to learn about Drawable Resources:

[Drawable Resources | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

This is what we're going to use to make this graphic.

First, we're going to start with the green bar.  The green bar is just going to take up the whole width and we're going to cover it up with the other graphics. This will be a *shape* drawable.

/res/drawable/green_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FF009900"/>
    <size android:height="12dp" android:width="12dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>
```

To get the pointy part, we're going to use a *nine-patch* image.  This is an image that can stretch in a manner that you control.

/res/drawable-mdpi/pointy.9.png:

[image: /res/drawable-mdpi/pointy.9.png]

I whipped this together in PhotoShop.  That little dot at the top center is saying that the middle can be stretched but not the ends.  And you can't see it against the white web page background, but there is a transparent corner at the very end of the graphic.

So we have to control how much the nine-patch is going to stretch.  For that we will use a *scale* drawable.

/res/drawable/scalepointy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pointy"
    android:scaleGravity="left|fill_vertical"
    android:scaleWidth="100%"/>
```

The `scaleWidth` says that we are going to use the drawable level to change the width of the nine-patch. Gravity of `left` means it will expand from left to right. `fill_vertical` keeps the level from changing the height too.

Now we have to stack these bars up.  We will use a *layer list* for that.

/res/drawable/pointybar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_bar" android:gravity="fill_horizontal"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/secondary" android:drawable="@drawable/scalepointy"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/primary" android:drawable="@drawable/scalepointy"/>
</layer-list>
```

Now we are going to use this as a background for a generic view:

(excerpt from /res/layout/activity_main.xml)

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/bargraph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pointybar"/>
```

Now for the code! Each drawable can have a *level*, and by setting the level we can change the drawable.  Drawable level goes from 0 to 10000, so for a percentage you multiply by 100 first.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Pointy Chart Demo");

        View view = findViewById(R.id.bargraph);

        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) view.getBackground();

        Drawable d1 = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.primary);
        d1.setLevel(6000); // 60%

        Drawable d2 = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.secondary);
        d2.setLevel(8000);  // 80%
    }
```

And this is important: Because `secondary` is listed before `primary` in `pointybar.xml`, we have to make sure that *we always set the higher level on `sscondary` and the lower level on `primary`.* If the higher level is on `primary` then it will cover up `secondary` and you won't see it.  (Maybe I should have named the ids better.  I was going too fast.)

And *this* is the final result!

[image: screenshot]

See how we did most of that in XML?  That's how Google wants you to do it.

Comment: Nice! Though, is it just me or the white spaces in the bar not the same as the off-white background?

Comment: Nice. very impressive. thank you Kris.

Comment: @cricket_007 It's not you.  I used full white for that slant shape, but the default theme must use an off-white for the background. The white is baked into the nine-patch PNG.

Comment: I considered coding a custom `Drawable` that would use a `Path` to draw the pointy shape, but that meant I would have to code all the rest of the drawables that I did in XML, because you can't inject custom drawables.  Security risk.